# Grav CMS get the url of uploaded file

Tags: twig, grav

I created file upload section

```
            header.custom.portsPositionFile:
          type: file
          destination: 'user/themes/hlg/uploads'
          label: Select file with port position list
          accept:
            - .pdf
```

Now I want to display it inside my link

```
<a href="{{ header.custom.portsPositionFile }}">my link</a>
```

this return me empty array. How Can I display link to uploaded file?

Comment: Where would you except the link to point to?

Comment: Are you trying to create a file upload section to the admin area or to the front-end (i.e. for the end users of your site)?

Comment: @martias I created file upload section in admin area. Next I want to display link on front page. Link sholud point to file that I uploaded in admin area.

Comment: @martias I want to display link for pdf file if it's important

Answer (score 1):

A file field will allow for multiple files to be uploaded, therefore it will create two object: the first object is the list of the uploaded files, the nested object within is a group of property/value for the given file.

If you only have a single pdf, you therefore should be able to get the link by using the first filter.
`{{ page.header.custom.portsPositionFile|first.name }}`

Comment: It doesn't work. Return me nothing. Empty paragraph :/

Comment: same for {{ page.header.custom.portsPositionFile|first.name }} ?

Comment: oh, sorry it should be `{{ page.media[page.header.custom.portsPositionFile|first.name].url }}` Can you confirm it works? I will edit my answer

Comment: So,  {{ page.header.custom.portsPositionFile|first.name }}  return me proper file name. But your second code {{ page.media[page.header.custom.portsPositionFile|first.name].‌​url }} return me empty paragraph too

Comment: But I think first.name construction should work with base_url

Comment: yes, it should work by constructing it with base url. Can you just try `{{ page.media[header.custom.portsPositionFile|first.name].‌​url }}`

Comment: Same :/ empty paragraph/link

Comment: ah, yes it's because you set destination to user/themes instead of a in the page itself. You therefore won't be able to use page.media on this page. Constructing the url with base_url will be easier in this case

Comment: ok, so where should I set destination? Create for example dir "uploads" in main dir with site? For now I have base_url solution

Comment: You can use `destination: 'self@'` and it will store the pdf in the page itself, and you should be able to use page.media

Answer (score 0):

From what I see in my *frontmatter* it outputs `path` not `url` so if you want this to work with the file being saved to any destination and not just `@self` then I'd try this:

`{{ page.media[header.custom.portsPositionFile|first.path]​ }}`